# Erratic seed behavior with rbinom(prob=0.5) in R

Tags: r, random

I have found what I would consider erratic behavior (but for which I hope there is a simple explanation) in `R`'s use of seeds in conjunction with `rbinom()` when `prob=0.5` is used.  General idea: To me, if I set the seed, run `rbinom()` once (i.e. conduct a single random process), despite what value `prob` is set to, the random
seed should change by one increment.  Then, if I again set the seed to the same value, and run another random process (such as `rbinom()` again, but maybe with a different value of `prob`), the seed should again change to the same value as it did for the previous single random process.

I have found `R` does exactly this as long as I'm using `rbinom()` with any `prob!=0.5`.  Here is an example:

**Compare seed vector, `.Random.seed`, for two probabilities other than 0.5:**

```
set.seed(234908)
x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.4)
temp1 <- .Random.seed

set.seed(234908)
x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.3)
temp2 <- .Random.seed

any(temp1!=temp2)
> [1] FALSE
```

**Compare seed vector, `.Random.seed`, for prob=0.5 vs. prob!=0.5:**

```
set.seed(234908)
x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.5)
temp1 <- .Random.seed

set.seed(234908)
x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.3)
temp2 <- .Random.seed
any(temp1!=temp2)
> [1] TRUE

temp1==temp2
> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> [8]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
...
```

I have found this for all comparisions of `prob=0.5` against all other probabilities
in the set {0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9}.  Similarly, if I compare any values of `prob` from
{0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9} other than 0.5, the `.Random.seed` vector is always element-by-element equal.  These facts also hold true for either odd or even `size` within `rbinom()`.

To make it even more strange (I apologize that this is a little convoluted - it's relevant to the way my function is written), when I use probabilities saved as elements in a vector, I have same problem if 0.5 is first element, but not second.  Here is the example for this case:

**First case: 0.5 is the first probability referenced in the vector**

```
set.seed(234908)
MNAR <- c(0.5,0.3)
x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=MNAR[1])
y <- rbinom(n=1,size=50,prob=MNAR[2])
temp1 <- .Random.seed

set.seed(234908)
MNAR <- c(0.1,0.3)
x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=MNAR[1])
y <- rbinom(n=1,size=50,prob=MNAR[2])
temp2 <- .Random.seed

any(temp1!=temp2)
> [1] TRUE

any(temp1!=temp2)
> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> [8]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

**Second case: 0.5 is the second probability referenced in the vector**

```
set.seed(234908)
MNAR <- c(0.3,0.5)
x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=MNAR[1])
y <- rbinom(n=1,size=50,prob=MNAR[2])
temp1 <- .Random.seed

set.seed(234908)
MNAR <- c(0.1,0.3)
x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=MNAR[1])
y <- rbinom(n=1,size=50,prob=MNAR[2])
temp2 <- .Random.seed

any(temp1!=temp2)
> [1] FALSE
```

Again, I find that despite the values used for `prob` and `size`, this pattern holds.  Can anyone explain this mystery to me?  It's causing quite a problem because results that should be the same are coming up different because the seed is for some reason used/calculated differently when `prob=0.5` but in no other instance.

Comment: Perhaps a more concise example of this behavior would be `set.seed(123);rbinom(1,60,0.5);rbinom(1,60,0.3); set.seed(123);rbinom(1,60,0.2);rbinom(1,60,0.3); set.seed(123);rbinom(1,60,0.4);rbinom(1,60,0.3)` ?

Comment: I don't understand why this causes problems to your code. Is the `prob` parameter a user input? Or is it random too?

Comment: My guess is that `prob = 0.5` is a special case in the way the function is implemented. You will notice that `prob = 0` and `prob = 1` also lead to a different `.Random.seed`.

Comment: I would go to https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/rbinom.c  , search for `unif_rand()`, and follow the logic through ...

Comment: @flodel Would you agree that in my example `rbinom(1,60,0.3)` ought to return the same value each time?

Comment: An interesting result using @joran's example above is that you get back on your feet if you make `prob = 0.2` or `prob = 0.4` draw two numbers instead of one. It suggests that `prob = 0.5` requires drawing twice as many random numbers than the other probs. That theory also checks out by replacing `60` with `120` in the OP's `x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.3)` case.

Comment: It's user-input - a simulation.Upon varying prob, I noticed the results weren't changing (I hadn't yet specified a vector with 0.5 as the first element), which allowed me to see theoretically why. However, I then happened upon the case above and have no explanation as to why. Now I'm concerned because when you set a seed, you (or I, at least) expect it to use the seed similarly for the same number of random processes. I feel, despite my specific application, it's worrisome in general.

Comment: Yes, the 0.5 being the culprit didn't go unnoticed and I felt it was obviously some sort of special case with how the function works, but I don't know why. It's worrisome in that my results look different simply because the seed gets off at one point. It's misleading and makes me wonder where else this might happen...

Comment: @Meg The simple workaround is to save the seed before calling `rbinom` and restore it after...

Comment: @Meg As flodel and Ben's comments are suggesting, I think it's likely that if there's a problem, it's only in `rbinom`, not the RNG process itself, or in other random functions.

Comment: @joran `rhyper` also seems to use rejection sampling, so it could affect the seed differently for different parameters. Why do you think this is likely only a problem in rbinom?

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft That was a guess, and a hopeful one at that.

Comment: HA! Look at the code Ben pointed to: there are sections for `n*p >=  30` and `n*p < 30`. The former uses two calls to `unif_rand()`, the latter a single one. Now notice that your example used `prob = 0.5` and `size = 60`, i.e. `n*p == 30`! Test with `size = 59` and the behavior disappears!

Comment: I'm surprised `rbinom` doesn't call `rnorm` when `n*p >= 30`

Comment: @flodel: write that up as an answer!

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft I'm running an iterative algorithm within my user-written function (which I repeat a large number of times), which calls many random processes, hence I want the seed to change after the initial setting. However, I think I could use this in some way... Will think about it more - thanks!

Answer (score 40):

So let's turn our comments into an answer. Thanks to Ben Bolker for putting us on the right track with a link to the code: https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/nmath/rbinom.c and the suggestion to track down where `unif_rand()` is called.

A quick scan and it seems that the code is broken into two sections, delimited by the comments:

```
/*-------------------------- np = n*p >= 30 : ------------------- */
```

and

```
/*---------------------- np = n*p < 30 : ------------------------- */
```

Inside each of these, the number of calls to `unif_rand` is not the same (two versus one.)

So for a given `size` (`n`), your random seed may end up in a different state depending on the value of `prob` (`p`): whether `size * prob >= 30` or not.

With that in mind, all the results you got with your examples should now make sense:

```
# these end up in the same state
rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.4) # => np <  30
rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.3) # => np <  30

# these don't
rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.5) # => np >= 30
rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.3) # => np <  30

# these don't
{rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.5)  # np >= 30
 rbinom(n=1,size=50,prob=0.3)} # np <  30
{rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.1)  # np <  30
 rbinom(n=1,size=50,prob=0.3)} # np <  30

# these do
{rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.3)  # np <  30
 rbinom(n=1,size=50,prob=0.5)} # np <  30
{rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.1)  # np <  30
 rbinom(n=1,size=50,prob=0.3)} # np <  30
```

Comment: That's great. However, I guess for me I'm still in trouble, as the sample size is drawn at random in my code (I just picked some numbers here for illustration). It's good to know where it's going wrong at least, but my simulation will still suffer. And this still makes me uncomfortable, haha. Thanks everyone!

Comment: This also explains why it happened at different iterations within my larger algorithm (that calls rbinom()) when I toyed around with changing the seed and function parameters - it would have altered when the sample sizes for rbinom() were > or < 30 (since this is also determined by a random process).

Comment: @Meg Now that we know what is going on, you should be able to deal with it either by making sure you use the same `prob` values in comparison runs, or by calling `set.seed` at multiple (matching) locations in your code to "reset" the common sequences.

Comment: Hmmm...maybe not that straight-forward after all: `set.seed(234); x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.4)` vs. `set.seed(234); x <- rbinom(n=1,size=60,prob=0.9)`.  The first has np < 30, the second > 30, but they end up the same...

Comment: Why not post to R-devel as a feature request? It seems like rbinom should have consistent effect on the random number stream regardless of parameter values; runif does.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft I still have to think about the implications - I'm running an iterative function that repeats until convergence, then I run that function a large number of times to calculate empirical bias and SD. Many random processes feed into each other, so it could "go wrong" at multiple points for a given run of the function. It's possible to "regulate" the seed, but I do need it to vary to get different estimates from each run. Also, as a larger issue, it still concerns me. I happened to "see" it here, but my guess is it has affected others' work unknowingly and will continue to do so.

Comment: @MartinMorgan - couldn't agree more. Like I've said (too many times now, sorry) - this is a general red flag for me. I found and can work around the error, but for those who don't know...

Comment: Also, just for everyone's information: The details are specific to my case, but I think this answer also solves the issue when it's caused by the vector of probabilities. It has to do with the sample sizes used in `rbinom()` that end up getting "paired" with either the first or second element of the probability vector (again, it's because of how my function is written). Still wondering about the example I posted a few comments above, however, which doesn't fit the pattern... Maybe R inconsistently uses two seeds (i.e. either one **or** two) when np > 30?

Comment: The `np>30` algorithm uses a rejection method -- there are two uniform random samples drawn *for every iteration of the method*, which means that the number of samples drawn will depend not just on the parameters, but on the current state of the RNG. I think this reinforces @BrianDigg's answer that your desired behaviour may not be practical.  (@MartinMorgan's comment that `runif` has a consistent effects on the stream and that therefore all `r*`'s should isn't really fair: `runif` is the fundamental building block and calls `unif_rand` directly.

Comment: [continued] unless you can always use a deterministic transformation method, you won't be able to make the guarantees you want.

Answer (score 15):

I'm going to take a contrarian position on this question and claim that the expectations are not appropriate and are not supported by the documentation. The documentation does not make any claim about what side effects (specifically on `.Random.seed`) can be expected by calling `rbinom`, or how those side effects may or may not be the same in various cases.

`rbinom` has three parameters: `n`, `size`, and `prob`. Your expectation is that, for a random seed set before calling `rbinom`, `.Random.seed` will be the same after calling `rbinom` for a given `n` and **any** values of `size` and `prob` (or maybe any finite values of `size` and `prob`). You certainly realize that it would be different for different values of `n`. `rbinom` doesn't guarantee that or imply that.

Without knowing the internals of the function, this can't be known; as the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18908655/892313) showed, the algorithm is different based on the product of `size` and `prob`. And the internals may change so these specific details may change.

At least, in this case, the resulting `.Random.seed` will be the same after every call of `rbinom` which has the *same* `n`, `size` *and* `prob`. I can construct a pathological function for which this is not even true:

```
seedtweak <- function() {
  if(floor(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time())$sec * 10) %% 2) {
    runif(1)
  }
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

Basically, this function looks a whether the tenths of the second of the time is odd or even to decided whether or not to draw a random number. Run this function and `.Random.seed` may or may not change:

```
rs <- replicate(10, {
  set.seed(123) 
  seedtweak()
  .Random.seed
})
all(apply(rs, 1, function(x) Reduce(`==`, x)))
```

The best you can (should?) hope for is that a given set of code with *all* the inputs/parameters the same (including the seed) will always give identical results. Expecting identical results when only *most* (or only some) of the parameters are the same is not realistic unless all the functions called make those guarantees.

Comment: +1. I totally agree. Moreover, it may be simply impossible to guarantee this kind of reproducibility; consider, for instance, rejection sampling.

Comment: great argument & write up!